# Import Global Address Book from Outlook to Excel or Power BI - Power Query

Tags: excel, outlook, powerbi, active-directory, powerquery

Has anyone experience how to import global address book from Outlook to Excel/Power BI using Power Query?

I managed to retrieve some of users from my Companies Email using Data from > Exchange Online

```
let
Source = Exchange.Contents("XYZ.com"),
People = Source{[Name="People"]}[Data]
in
People
```

But it doesnt give me whole list of Outlook users from the Company...

I found different code but doesnt work for me, it says: my domain doesnt exist. And I am not very familiar with Active Directory and so on...any inputs and tricks?

```
let
Source = ActiveDirectory.Domains("CompanyDomain.com"),
CompanyDomain.com = Source{[Domain = "CompanyDomain.com"]}[Object Categories],
user = CompanyDomain.com{[Category = "user"]}[Objects],
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(user, {"displayName", "user", 
"organizationalPerson"}),
#"Expanded organizationalPerson" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", 
"organizationalPerson", {"department"}, {"department"}),
#"Expanded user 1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded organizationalPerson", "user", 
{"mail"}, {"mail"})
in
#"Expanded user 1"
```

I am using Office365 version.

Answer (score 1):

Create a query that is just the source line above.  For example:

```
let
    Source = ActiveDirectory.Domains("yourdomain.com")
in
    Source
```

In Power Query, when you click on the Source line on the right, what does it show? In my case, I get a table of domains. It would be one of those values you would use in the "CompanyDomain.com =" line above.

If Source is giving you the error about not finding the domain, then you'll have to have someone tell you what that value is for your company.  (Mine was automatically filled in when I chose the Active Directory connector, and it's not just CompanyName.com.)

Hope it helps,

Alan